# Performance: Save default image or encode it every time

Tags: java, spring, performance, base64

I have a small REST application which is basically a telephone book with user-pictures. It queries a database of about 5000 users, until now, only 2-300 of them have pictures, so I have a default image which I use in those other cases.

In my ImageHandler class I have a procedure which encodes this default image.

Now I want to know quite general: 
Is it better to save the default image base64 encoded as a static String in the class (so, encode it once the application starts up). Or not save it as a String and encode it from the image (png; 4KB) everytime it is requested?

This application is written in Java/Spring, but I'm also happy for some non language specific input.

Is it really only a matter of reload time versus memory usage?

```
public static String encode(String imagePath) {
    if (!STANDARD_USER_IMAGE_BASE64.isEmpty()) {
        return STANDARD_USER_IMAGE_BASE64;
    }

    String base64Image = "";
    File file = new File(imagePath);
    try (FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        // Reading a Image file from file system
        byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        imageInFile.read(imageData);
        STANDARD_USER_IMAGE_BASE64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageData);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Image not found" + e);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception while reading the Image " + ioe);
    }
    return STANDARD_USER_IMAGE_BASE64;

}
```

Comment: When I needed to do this I stored the default image in client application so I didnt need to request the default image every time. I think this is a good way to improve performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This would be a sleek solution but unfortunately I don't have access to the clients.